# iOS - Displaying multiple labels inline

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

[image]I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight on displaying multiple labels inline on a UITableView header. I understand this can be done through Autolayout or programatic layout.

Comment: show us somthing, atleast the way you want it with a picture

Comment: @Graham added a picture. Ideally these should be evenly spaced when rendered.

Comment: using autolayout you can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a video tutorial for you.just refer it and follow the steps.you may need 3 min.(use ctrl + 3finger drag or mouse    to drag.).best of luck

https://youtu.be/Q-hrWKcwxMw

Comment: This is a really good tutorial to cover this! Most videos seem only touch upon adding a label and an image, but this one is much more helpful for my case! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a delegate method that asks for a view for the header. You can configure a custom view to fill your needs and set it to the return value of this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  #code
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to mention that I am using viewForHeaderInSection, however, my issue mostly seems to be making the layout come out evenly spaced between labels.

Answer (score 0):

Did you display fixed number of labels?

If yes,`UIStackView` is easier but only available in iOS9 and later.you can also add constraints to make them equal width and leave the same space from each other.This is universal.

If no,`UICollectionView` is the best solution.How to use `UICollectionView`,there're too many tutorials.

Comment: I've already made a lot of progress using UITableView, so I'd like to keep using that class if possible. UIStackView would be great but iOS 7 support is a must.

Comment: @xxyyzz you don't need to abandon your table view,just add a vertical collection view onto header view.

Comment: That is a neat idea! I'll try that too.